# Zend Framework Installation on xampp errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to install zend on xampp and l am continuosly getting errors.

Firstly l am getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\ZendSkeletonApplication\public\index.php on line 24

Line 24 is as follows:

```
if (! class_exists(Application::class)) {
```

I solved this by making Application::class a string.

then l got the second error below:

> Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\ZendSkeletonApplication\public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\ZendSkeletonApplication\public\index.php on line 22
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\ZendSkeletonApplication\public/../vendor/autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\ZendSkeletonApplication\public\index.php on line 22
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load application. - Type `composer install` if you are developing locally. - Type `vagrant ssh -c 'composer install'` if you are using Vagrant. - Type `docker-compose run zf composer install` if you are using Docker. ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\ZendSkeletonApplication\public\index.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\ZendSkeletonApplication\public\index.php on line 25

where am l supposed to find the vendor folder with the autoload page? I would lie to solve to it today , lol, l have been attempting it for days unend.

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Composer is the recommended way to install Zend Framework (this creates the vendor folder). Personally I've never done this using Windows, but there are some instructions here which should help: https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/#windows-users-using-wamp

From the look of the first error message in your question, the version of PHP you're running is too low to run the current version of ZF, so you might need to upgrade PHP first. (Composer would normally tell you this during installation.)

Comment: Thank you Tim , It did but silly me, l continued to install none the less, lm not very experienced with installation of modules. How do l upgrade my php?

Comment: Install a newer version of XAMPP

Comment: thanks Tim and RiggyFolloy, lm installing as we speak, and lm so excited cant wait to start experimenting